# DateTime ParseExact Throws Exception

Tags: c#, datetime

Well i am trying to parse that date

> **5/10/2013 002704**

```
        var stt = "5/10/2013 002704";
        result = DateTime.ParseExact(stt, "dd-MM-yyyy HHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

but i get this **Exception**

> **String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**

**However!,** this code works to parse only the time `*without date*`

```
        var stt = "002704";
        result = DateTime.ParseExact(stt, "HHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Well i hope someone helps me with that problem and thanks in advance...

**HINT** : THIS ALSO FAILS

```
    var stt = "5/10/2013 002704";
    result = DateTime.ParseExact(stt, "dd/MM/yyyy HHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

***Well it works! thanks to every one helped me here for his\her very nice help that i really appreciate very much. Also i will take the XY Problem into account next time :D.***

Comment: You're using `/` to delimit your date in the sample data and then checking for `-` in the parsing.

Comment: cus i tried to change it `to /` with no luck

Comment: No i do. What do you expecting more ?... This is the code that is doing the function and this is the code that throws the exception and you have the time i am trying to parse !!

Comment: @RuneS, you would be well served to make sure the code you show is the code you wanted us to look at.  Not the code you randomly tried in desparation.

Comment: You don't have enough digits, use "d/M/yyyy HHmmss"

Comment: @HansPassant : well what if the program started on 10/10/2013 if i changed to `d/M/yyyy` it will throw the same exception

Comment: The short answer is, if you're going to use Parse**Exact**(), you'd better be sure the string you're supplying matches the format specifier. Otherwise, consider using `DateTime.Parse()`. What is the real use case behind this question? That might be more constructive.

Comment: @RuneS it works, try it yoursef

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, you're doing a parse exact with `dd` but passing in `d`. Change your input string to `"05/10/2013 002704"`, and make sure you're using `/` in your delimiter.

```
var stt = "05/10/2013 002704";
result = DateTime.ParseExact(stt, "dd/MM/yyyy HHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**Edit**

Sorry, I had to take a phone call and couldn't finish my thought. Instead of using `dd` you probably want `d`. It will work with `05/10/2013` or any number up to 31 (as pointed out in the comments on the question). Also, I think @DanJ made a great comment reference the use case of this method.

> The short answer is, if you're going to use Parse**Exact**(), you'd better be sure the string you're supplying matches the format specifier.

If you are going to move forward with `ParseExact` then you should use:

```
result = DateTime.ParseExact(stt, "d/MM/yyyy HHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: how to change it to suit both ?

Comment: or atleast how could i get the date in that format from DateTime.Now

Comment: `d` instead of `dd` is what you want.

Comment: wee another small question how could i get the date in that format M/D/YYYY not D/M/YYYY

Comment: @RuneS You should ask another question, however I would NOT recommend just asking how to format the date M/D/YYYY but tell us what you are trying to do. You are likely doing things in a difficult way and there is likely a simpler solution to what you want to do. Please read up on what is the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), tell us X (Something with date manipulation I assume) instead of asking about Y (parsing and formatting dates to strings).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain : Well it just worked fine now and i will take you advice into account next time thank you all guys for your very nice help and i really appreciate it very much

Comment: In my rush to answer the question, I acted like an American and just read the date and wrote out `MM`. Should have referenced `dd` instead. I have updated my answer to reflect the fix.

Answer (score 3):

You have two things wrong:

1. You are using `dd` for the day of the month, which expects a leading `0` if the day is a single digit. Use `d` instead.
2. As others have said, you are using `-` in your format, but `/` in your input data.

Comment: how to make it accepts both dd and d

Comment: `d` will accept both `5` and `05`.

Answer (score 2):

first ,you are parsing with format string that contains `-` (dd-MM-yyyy) while the string contains `/` (5/10/2013).

another thing is that day component should be `d`, not `dd` because it is `5` not `05`.

```
  var stt = "5/10/2013 002704";
    result = DateTime.ParseExact(stt, "d/MM/yyyy HHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: it fails try it yourself

Comment: @RuneS updated the answer, check it now

Comment: but what if the days are 10/10/2013... because i am not using a static date it should be changing as the time the program execute in

Comment: d works with numbers `1` through `31`, dd works with `01` through `31`

Comment: `d` will accept both 05 and 5

Answer (score 2):

Why all the arguing over whether it should be "d" versus "dd", or "M" versus "MM"?

**You all can have your cake AND eat it too!**

They are all valid, so treat them all as valid.  Build yourself an **ARRAY** of allowed formats and pass that to DateTime.TryParseExact().  Now all those cases will be handled like you'd expect them to:

```
        DateTime result;
        var stt = "5/10/2013 002704";
        string[] formats = { "d/M/yyyy HHmmss", "dd/MM/yyyy HHmmss", "d/MM/yyyy HHmmss", "dd/M/yyyy HHmmss" };
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(stt, formats, null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
        {
            // ... do something with "result" in here ...
            Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            // ... parse failed ...
        }
```